# Flutter - New page route is only leading to a blank page

Tags: flutter, dart

I've already created one page route, to the `feed_page`, but now, when going from `feed_page` to `new_post_page`, the `new_post_page` is just blank on the simulated phone.

Here's the obligatory code dump :)

In this first code dump (page of origin), I omitted the other contents of the `appBar` and the `body` of the scaffold:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:we_rise/post_card.dart';
import 'new_post_page.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FeedPageState createState() => _FeedPageState();
}

class _FeedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[

// PAGE ROUTE IN QUESTION

          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewPostPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then the problematic new page that is just showing up blank in the simulated phone:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class NewPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPostPageState createState() => _NewPostPageState();
}

class _NewPostPageState extends State<NewPostPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFC033),
        title: const Text('New Post'),
      ),
      body: Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder')
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove Expanded widget from body only keep Column widget and Run.

Comment: Thank you very much @BhoomikaChauhan , if you wanted to post this as an answer, I'll set it as the answer for this.

Comment: and another thing is  if your text is too long you can wrap this with `Expanded` in `Column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in body, Remove Expanded widget from body only keep Column widget and Run, set as below.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class NewPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPostPageState createState() => _NewPostPageState();
}

class _NewPostPageState extends State<NewPostPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFC033),
        title: const Text('New Post'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder')
          ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ex:
=> You are Remove Expanded   Widigit

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class NewPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPostPageState createState() => _NewPostPageState();
}

class _NewPostPageState extends State<NewPostPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFC033),
        title: const Text('New Post'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder')
          ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```